# Does super-essentiality preclude compatibility with Anaxagoras?

Tags: ontology, philosophy-of-religion, presocratics

On the one hand, God as superessential implies:
Part of God's divine nature is to be found in humans, and indeed all things

This seems to be consonant with the view of the cosmos held by [Anaxagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaxagoras): that imprints of all of existence exist in the Monad as a kind of ontological fractal.

However, on the other hand, God as superessential also implies: God is entirely transcendent and his ontological locus is beyond classification or understanding, standing apart from existence though existence at the same time partakes of his nature.

### Question

Can a cosmogony that upholds superessentialism still be congruent with Anaxagoras framework, even though God/Monad/First cause is ontologically segregated from the rest of existence?

Comment: It is always difficult to apply modern concepts, like "superessentialism" to Presocratic philosophers, like Anaxagoras, whose [work survives only in fragments quoted by later philosophers and commentators](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/anaxagoras/#LifWor).

Comment: True, though, in my opinion, this is where the fun is. While the presocratics are certainly older, a fuzzy notion of superessentiality is itself pretty old, going back 2000 years. St Dionysius puts forward some [quasi-superessentiality concepts here](https://www.tertullian.org/fathers/areopagite_06_mystic_theology.htm)